# jq - how to conditionally filter out objects

Tags: json, select, jq

I'm trying to vastly simplify a large JSON file, and part of that process is conditionally filtering out some of the objects. I have a series of conditions I'd like to apply, but I'm not able to get even a single condition to work properly.

I've been working with the jq documentation, but I'm not a pro developer so it's challenging to read it. I found an example of this in another stackoverflow thread, so I've been trying to adapt that.

My source JSON file, while large, is clean and well-formed. It's basically one flat array of objects. A few of the keys in the objects are arrays as well, but I'll be discarding most of those anyway. Below is a sample, showing the first object:

```
[
   {
      "object":"card",
      "id":"86bf43b1-8d4e-4759-bb2d-0b2e03ba7012",
      "oracle_id":"0004ebd0-dfd6-4276-b4a6-de0003e94237",
      "multiverse_ids":[
         15862
      ],
      "mtgo_id":15870,
      "mtgo_foil_id":15871,
      "tcgplayer_id":3094,
      "name":"Static Orb",
      "lang":"en",
      "released_at":"2001-04-11",
      "uri":"https://api.scryfall.com/cards/86bf43b1-8d4e-4759-bb2d-0b2e03ba7012",
      "scryfall_uri":"https://scryfall.com/card/7ed/319/static-orb?utm_source=api",
      "layout":"normal",
      "highres_image":true,
      "mana_cost":"{3}",
      "cmc":3.0,
      "type_line":"Artifact",
      "oracle_text":"As long as Static Orb is untapped, players can't untap more than two permanents during their untap steps.",
      "colors":[

      ],
      "color_identity":[

      ],
      "legalities":{
         "standard":"not_legal",
         "future":"not_legal",
         "historic":"not_legal",
         "pioneer":"not_legal",
         "modern":"not_legal",
         "legacy":"legal",
         "pauper":"not_legal",
         "vintage":"legal",
         "penny":"not_legal",
         "commander":"legal",
         "brawl":"not_legal",
         "duel":"legal",
         "oldschool":"not_legal"
      },
      "games":[
         "paper",
         "mtgo"
      ],
      "reserved":false,
      "foil":true,
      "nonfoil":true,
      "oversized":false,
      "promo":false,
      "reprint":true,
      "variation":false,
      "set":"7ed",
      "set_name":"Seventh Edition",
      "set_type":"core",
      "collector_number":"319",
      "digital":false,
      "rarity":"rare",
      "flavor_text":"The warriors fought against the paralyzing waves until even their thoughts froze in place.",
      "card_back_id":"0aeebaf5-8c7d-4636-9e82-8c27447861f7",
      "artist":"Terese Nielsen",
      "artist_ids":[
         "eb55171c-2342-45f4-a503-2d5a75baf752"
      ],
      "illustration_id":"6f8b3b2c-252f-4f95-b621-712c82be38b5",
      "border_color":"white",
      "frame":"1997",
      "full_art":false,
      "textless":false,
      "booster":true,
      "story_spotlight":false,
      "edhrec_rank":1836,
      "prices":{
         "usd":"17.07",
         "usd_foil":"72.02",
         "eur":"10.73",
         "tix":"0.79"
      },
      "related_uris":{
         "gatherer":"https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=15862",
         "tcgplayer_decks":"https://decks.tcgplayer.com/magic/deck/search?contains=Static+Orb\u0026page=1\u0026utm_campaign=affiliate\u0026utm_medium=api\u0026utm_source=scryfall",
         "edhrec":"https://edhrec.com/route/?cc=Static+Orb",
         "mtgtop8":"https://mtgtop8.com/search?MD_check=1\u0026SB_check=1\u0026cards=Static+Orb"
      }
   }
]
```

First, I'm attempting to add a condition which will remove objects where the key "reprint" has the value true. This is what I've got so far:

`curl -s https://archive.scryfall.com/bulk-data/default-cards/default-cards-20200529170427.json | jq .[] - "map(select(.reprint[] | contains (\"true\")))" > reprints_removed.json`

But I keep getting this error:

`jq: error: Could not open file map(select(.reprint[] | contains ("true"))): No such file or directory`

Once I've got that working, I'd like to start using compound conditions. So, for instance, next I'll remove objects where either the key "reprint" is "true" or the key "border_color" is "silver".

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The value of .reprint in each of the objects in the top-level array is strictly boolean, as can be seen by running:

```
jq 'map(.reprint)|unique'
```

So an efficient way to select the objects for which .reprint is `false` is to use the filter:

```
map(select(.reprint == false))
```

This will preserve the array structure.  If you just want the JSON objects as a stream, you could write:

```
.[] | select(.reprint == false)
```

Since .reprint is strictly boolean, there are various equivalent formulations of the condition.

### Negation

If .reprint were multi-valued, then to exclude the objects for which `.reprint == true` you could use negation:

```
.[] | select(.reprint == true | not)
```

Notice that in jq, `not` is a 0-ary filter -- it has no argument.

### Compound conditions

> remove objects where either the key "reprint" is "true" or the key "border_color" is "silver".

```
map(select( (.reprint == true or .border_color == "silver") | not))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I put it all together, used the stream version, escaped the quotation marks and parentheses, and tried running this: `curl -s https://archive.scryfall.com/bulk-data/default-cards/default-cards-20200529170427.json | jq .[] | select\( \(.reprint == true or .border_color == \"silver\"\) | not\) > test.json`. But I'm getting this error: `Command 'not)' not found, did you mean:

  command 'note' from deb note

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

select(: command not found`

Comment: You will find it much easier if you put the jq program into a file, say program.jq, and use it with jq -f program.jq